# Mule Munit with Choice followed by Dataweave transform

Tags: mule, dataweave, munit

I have a flow that has a Choice followed by a Dataweave transform.
Input to the flow is json.
The choice has this when statement:

```
<when expression="#[payload.resultSet1.size() >= 1]">
```

The flow works well:

```
<flow name="test1">
 <db:stored-procedure doc:name="MyStoredProc"></db:stored-procedure>
 <choice doc:name="data found?">
        <when expression="#[payload.resultSet1.size() >= 1]">
            <dw:transform-message doc:name="CreateResponse">
                     <dw:set-payload resource="classpath:/dataweave/someDataweave.dwl" />
              </dw:transform-message>
        </when>
       <otherwise>
              <logger message="False:  payload:#[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Log-False"/>
        </otherwise>
    </choice>  
</flow>
```

Now I’m trying to create an Munit test for it.  In order to get the choice to work, I had to do some playing with the data.
The choice now works but now the dataweave transform throws an exception because it says the json data is missing quotes.
The munit:

```
<munit:test name="test1-tryit" description="Test">
      <mock:when messageProcessor=".*:.*" doc:name="Mock MyStoredProcResults">
        <mock:with-attributes>
            <mock:with-attribute name="doc:name" whereValue="#['MyStoredProc']"/>
        </mock:with-attributes>
        <mock:then-return payload="#[flowVars.jsonStoredProcResponse]" mimeType="text/json"/>
    </mock:when>
    <set-payload value="#[getResource('myTestData.json').asStream()]"  doc:name="GetStoredProcResponse" mimeType="application/json"/>
    <json:json-to-object-transformer returnClass="java.lang.Object" doc:name="JSON to Object"/>
    <set-variable variableName="jsonStoredProcResponse" value="#[payload]" doc:name="jsonStoredProcResponse" />
   <flow-ref name="test1" doc:name="Flow-ref to test1 flow" />
```

The data in myTestData.json file looks like this:
{"resultSet1": [{ "field1":"123" } ]}

Not sure how to resolve this issue and get both the choice and the transform to work.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you please add the full text of the loggeg exception? If you could add more details about the problem, then it would be easier to find out what is the problem. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Try using below groovy script:

    <scripting: script name="mockDataBaseResponse" engine="groovy" doc:name="Script"><![CDATA[
    Hashmap<String,String> cursor = new Hashmap<String,String>();
    cursor.put("field1","123");
    LinkedList List = new LinkedList();
    List.add(cursor);
    Hashmap<String,Object> cursorMap = new Hashmap<String,Object>();
    cursorMap.put("resultSet1",List);
    return cursorMap;]]>
    </scripting:script>

Mock payload using script:

<mock:then-return payload="#[resultOfScript('mockDataBaseresponse')]" mimeType="text/java"/>

Also include this script file in you Munit xml file.
```